# Как запустить команду по нажатию кнопки в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

```
 @dp.message_handler(commands=['hi6'])
 async def process_hi6_command(message: types.Message):
     await message.reply("hi", reply_markup=markup3)

 @dp.message_handler(commands='bot')
 async def start_cmd_handler(message: types.Message):
    keyboard_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    text_and_data = (('info', 'info'),('test', 'test'))
    await message.reply("hi", reply_markup=keyboard_markup)

 @dp.callback_query_handler(text='info')
 async def inline_kb_answer_callback_handler(query: types.CallbackQuery):
     answer_data = query.data

     # I WANT RUN hi6

     text = f'Unexpected callback data {answer_data!r}!'
     await bot.send_message(query.from_user.id, text)`
```

Хочу запустить выполнение команды в обработчике сообщений или как можно назначить кнопку InlineKeyboardButton чтобы выполнялась команда бота?

Answer (score 0):

Никак. По крайней мере через инлайн кнопки точно. Копируйте строку и будет все в шоколаде.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='info')
async def inline_kb_answer_callback_handler(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    answer_data = query.data

    # I WANT RUN hi6
    await message.reply("hi", reply_markup=markup3)

    text = f'Unexpected callback data {answer_data!r}!'
    await bot.send_message(query.from_user.id, text)`
```